# whats wrong in this php code is not inserting to DB

Tags: php, html

[image]

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok1'])){
 $nomo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nomo');
 $prenomo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prenomo');
 $emailo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'emailo');
 $ageo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ageo');
 $sexeo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sexeo');
 $villeo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'villeo');
 $cpo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpo');
 if (!empty($nomo) && !empty($prenomo)  && !empty($emailo) && !empty($ageo) && !empty($sexeo) &&  !empty($villeo) && !empty($cpo)){

$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "srv_msn";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_error()){
  die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
    . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO personne  (CP, EMAIL, PRENOM, NOM)
  values ('$cpo','$emailo','$prenomo','$nomo')";
  if ($conn->query($sql)){
    echo "New record is inserted sucessfully";
  }
  else{
    echo "Error: ". $sql ."
". $conn->error;
  
  $conn->close();
}
}
}
else {
  echo "Password should not be empty";
  die();
}
 } 
 ?>
```

if someone can please help me on this code i tried every single solution i found on google and youtube too , i have a form on my website project  and i want  the informations entered on the form to get inserted to mysql DB but it doesnt insert the information to the database

Comment: You are inserting 4 values in 4 columns and you're just specifing one column (NOM). Add all the columns. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: i did insert 4 values in 4 columns before but it didnt work either

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli_` functions, you should **ALWAYS** use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and the function [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to protect against SQL-Injections. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because it creates a severe SQL injection bug. **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data into a query directly. This can be very harmful if someones seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @AnwarElaajabi Could you post a screenshot of your table in your database?

Comment: i did just right now my friend the problem is i have another form of client and it  works and its inserts the information to the DB but this form in the code below i dont know whats wrong with it even i copied the same code